# How to get row with max sum?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I have a [technicians table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yflI.png), a [clients table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SreY9.png) and a [jobs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZM6C.png). My technicians model looks like this:

```
class Technician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :clients, through: :job_orders
end
```

My jobs model looks like this:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :technician
  belongs_to :client
end
```

And my clients model looks like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_orders
  has_many :technicians, through: :jobs
end
```

I am able to pull a list of how many jobs a technician has performed by doing

```
techs = Technician.all
techs.each do |tech|
  puts "#{tech.name} has been assigned #{tech.jobs.count} jobs"
end
```

Now how can I see the technician with the fewest jobs, or the client with the most job requests? I've been thinking of sorting by sum asc/desc, but I haven't been able to wrap my mind around the issue. I am **not** using rails, just plain old Ruby with the activerecord gem.

Comment: `Technician.joins(:jobs).order("SUM(jobs.id) ASC").limit(5)` will give you the technicians with the fewest jobs,  you can use `DESC` for those with the most jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what if I wanted to get just the one with the fewest or the most? Also, that gave me a SQLite3::SQLException: misuse of aggregate error.

Comment: Sorry, you actually count use `.joins(:jobs).select("COUNT(jobs.id) AS jobs_count").order(jobs_count: :asc).limit(5)` Though this would exclude technicians with zero jobs... not sure how to get around that issue

Comment: Doing Technicians.first.name gives me the name of the job.

Answer (score 0):

`Client.joins(:job_orders).order('COUNT(job_orders) DESC').group(:id).limit(1)` will give you the Client with the most amount of job orders,  `Technician.joins(:jobs).order('COUNT(jobs) ASC').group(:id).limit(1)` will give you the technicians with the fewest amount of jobs

**Edit: For Rails versions < 6.0**

Comment: I got "DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "COUNT(job_orders) DESC". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql(). (called from report at /Users/xxxxx/Development/guided-module-one-project-assessment-dumbo-web-062419/lib/menu2.rb:210)"

Comment: Oh wow. I guess I need to pay closer attention to my server logs. I haven't seen a warning like that yet :(. I'm on rails 4.2 at work and rails 5 at home when I do my own thing.

Comment: Still didn't work. I'm not using rails but plain Ruby if that matters.

Comment: Oh sorry ya, I assumed that you were using Rails and ActiveRecord

Comment: My best guess would be then to maybe do `Client.joins(:job_orders).select('COUNT(job_orders) as job_orders').order('jobs_orders DESC')` and then something similar with the technician part

Comment: @HuitZiloP I was reading some of the issues on Rails' GitHub page about the deprecation warning. They said that one way to get around that is to use something like `.order(Arel.sql('COUNT(job_orders)'))` They were saying that it's like strong params as security issue. That you have to opt out of what they did in order to have more security by default. And that if you're not taking in user supplied data, then it's 'safe'ish to use the raw sql